# Can I make an div bounce if it is flex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get an image inside of a div to bounce whenever my mouse hovers over it.

In order to explain the problem that I'm having, I made a quick mockup of what I want to happen in the snippet below.

I would like the text to bounce slightly whenever my mouse goes over the image/text/whatever.

The only thing that I could presumably figure is that items don't bounce whenever they are part of a flexbox scheme, however, I haven't been able to find any documentation to prove that.

Can someone explain how I can get that to bounce to occur, while using flexbox?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text').hover(function() {
   $(this).toggle("bounce",{times: 3}, "slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.one{
  margin:0;
  }

.container{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:gray;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:horizontally;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
   }
.dog{
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  }
.cat{
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="one">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="dog">
          <div class="text">Hello Dog</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cat">
          Hello Cat
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added in the jquery-ui scripts/css and it works fine:

The *bounce* effect that you are using is part of [`jQuery UI` library](https://api.jqueryui.com) - see [this for reference](https://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/).

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggle("bounce", {
      times: 3
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.dog {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.cat {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dog">
        <div class="text">Hello Dog</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cat">
        Hello Cat
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Guren let me know if this worked for you or did I miss something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: You beat me to it haha +1

Comment: @kukkuz What you did worked, but I'm trying to figure out what I did incorrectly or different. Can you be more specific? What is the Ajax link, and the css sheet you added at the top?

Comment: @kukkuz I see the problem, I was assuming that the bounce effect is not part of jQuery itself, but it is actually part of jQuery UI which is another version.

Answer (score 1):

get css file from the link i have provided and add to the head section and then use the specific keeywords on the texts or buttons or images and it should work. the link is http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/